# Multiple Heatmap Subplots: Same Heatbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

Here is how I am plotting my heatmap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplt as plt 

ax = plt.gca()
im = ax.imshow(values)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size='5%', pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

Now I would like to create a 2x2 subplot, with 4 different heatmaps, and all having the same heatbar. I am completely clueless on how to achieve that, and would appreciate any nudge into the right direction.

Comment: Its unclear what you want exactly. A figure with 4x4 subplots would have 16 subplots, not 4. Do you mean a 2x2 arrangement? And why do you want to use the same divider? Should they all have the same colorbar, or 4 (or 16) separate ones?

Comment: @tom Yes, 2x2. They should all have the same colorbar, as they have numbers from the same domain. Thus also only one divider (It'd otherwise be repetitive).

Comment: @tom Perhaps I note the confusion now. By "one divider", I meant one of those bars that label colors with numbers. Perhaps that's the colorbar - which I thought was just the bijection number -> color, not the visualization.. I'm checking now what's what.

Comment: Yep, I think you mean one colorbar. The divider is just a method in `matplotlib` to help split up axes (for example, to add a colorbar). See my answer which I think does what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using [`AxesGrid` from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axes-grid1). See the example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_grid.html) (Specifcally, look at the function `demo_grid_with_single_cbar` in that example).

I've modified that example slightly, for your case of a 2x2 grid with colorbar on the right.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid

# Some random data
values1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
values2 = np.random.rand(10,10)
values3 = np.random.rand(10,10)
values4 = np.random.rand(10,10)
vals = [values1,values2,values3,values4]

fig = plt.figure()

grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111,
                nrows_ncols=(2, 2),
                axes_pad=0.05,
                share_all=True,
                label_mode="L",
                cbar_location="right",
                cbar_mode="single",
                )

for val, ax in zip(vals,grid):
    im = ax.imshow(val, vmin=0, vmax=1)

grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im)

for cax in grid.cbar_axes:
    cax.toggle_label(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think that this answer is wrong, at least in newer versions of matplotlib. If I insert the values

    values1 = [[0.0, 0.1],[0.2, 0.3]]
    values2 = [[0.35, 0.36], [0.37, 0.38]]
    values3 = [[0.4, 0.5], [0.6, 0.7]]
    values4 = [[1.0, 0.9], [0.8, 0.75]]

in your code (note that minimal value in values4 is higher than maximal value in values1), it becomes obvious that the heatbar belongs only to the last graph: [![heat plot][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARvl3.png

Comment: Since your answer was accepted ... Should I ask this question again?

Comment: You just need to add a `vmin` and `vmax` to your calls to `imshow` to make sure all your plots use the same scaling. The example here is not wrong, it's just that all four subplots have the same min/max values, and so is different to your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! However, technically speaking, the four `np.random.rand(10,10)` arrays are also not on the same scale:)